# Open/Read a binary file - access rights

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert VB5 to .NET and cannot get a binary read to work. My VB.NET decode only reads the first two characters correctly. 
The (VB5->VB.NET) encode is

```
    ' Open file
    x = Rnd(-mKeyValue)
    filenum = FreeFile()
    Try
        FileOpen(filenum, Filename, OpenMode.Binary)
    Catch ex As IO.IOException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "File opening error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    ' write data
    filecontents = ""       

    For i = 1 To Len(stringdate)
        charnum = Asc(Mid(stringdate, i, 1))
        randomint = Int(256 * Rnd())
        charnum = charnum Xor randomint
        singlechar = Chr(charnum)
        FilePut(filenum, singlechar, i)
        filecontents = filecontents & singlechar
    Next i
```

And the (VB5->VB.NET) decode is

```
    x = Rnd(-mKeyValue)
    filenum = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(filenum, Filename, OpenMode.Binary)
    For i = 1 To LOF(filenum)

        'To VB.NET
        FileGet(filenum, singlechar, i)
        charnum = Asc(singlechar)
        Debug.Print("VB5 singlechar = " & singlechar)
        randomint = Int(256 * Rnd())
        charnum = charnum Xor randomint
        singlechar = Chr(charnum)
     Next i
```

My VB.NET code which fails (cannot read the file correctly) is;

```
      Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open))
        ' Loop through length of file.
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        Dim length As Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length


        While pos < length
            ' Read the integer.
            singlechar = reader.ReadChar()
            charnum = Asc(singlechar)    'singlechar is type Char
            randomint = Int(256 * Rnd())
            charnum = charnum Xor randomint
            singlechar = Chr(charnum)

            i += 1
        End While
    End Using
```

Can anyone help me with translation from VB5 to .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.Net everything is a **bit** shorter ;)

```
    ' get a string from an encrypted file file:
    Dim b() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path")
    For i = 0 To b.Length - 1
        b(i) = b(i) Xor (256 * Rnd())
    Next
    Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
```

Why read byte by byte (no sense to read 'char' anyway, since you only want the 8bit ASCII code), when .Net can read it at once? Your file is not larger > 100 MB, I assume? Then after getting the array, you simply XOR each element with your "random" value. If you dont need to be compatible to old versions, you might better use `Random`. Or maybe even better ... USE REAL ENCRYPTION (in .Net it's built-in!)

```
' put a string into a file
    Dim c() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The String you want to store encrypted")
    For i = 0 To c.Length - 1
        c(i) = c(i) Xor (256 * Rnd())
    Next
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes("another path", c)
```

Same for "encrypting". Convert the string to an array of byte (=ASCII values), XOR it and then write it back in ONE operation.

See the dangers of Unicode:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Beware of UNICODE ... !!!
    Using sw As New FileStream("foo.foo", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        ' with old VB you effectively wrote BYTE data
        sw.Write({65, 192}, 0, 2)
    End Using

    Using br As New BinaryReader(File.Open("foo.foo", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        ' You are telling. Net that you expect a CHAR, which is not ASCII, but UNICODE
        Dim c As Char = br.ReadChar
        Dim d As Char = br.ReadChar
        Dim cc = Asc(c)
        Dim dd = Asc(d)
        Debug.Print("65 -> {0}, 192 -> {1}", cc, dd)
    End Using

End Sub
```

The output is `65 -> 65, 192 -> 63`

Comment: igrimpe. Thanks. The decrypt almost works with the converted VB5 code. It runs but not all characters are translated back to the original. I had hoped to have a common licence file (<100 characters) for legacy VB5 and .NET, perhaps that is not possible. I have looked up REAL ENCRYPTION; it seems that not all .NET code is shorter/simpler...;)

Comment: @Graham: WHICH code works "partly"? Your (3rd block) code, or mine? If it's yours: ReadChar reads a CHAR which in VB.Net is by default a UNICODE character. This means that all characters beyond "true" ASCII will not return their initial value. Better read BYTE since you wrote bytes with your old VB5 code. I've updated my answer with a little sample code to show the problem.

Comment: @grimpe It is your code that partially works, the first two characters match the original string but the rest don't. My third block fails miserably. Using your examples I have now rewritten the .NET security and will use a different licence filename. This won't really matter as the security dlls (VB5, NET) will only read their appropriate file so if the user puts both files into either directory only the relevant one will be read. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Graham: Please be aware that a "license protection" with VB.Net is a bit more complicated than with VB.classic, because your .exe is not native code, but MSIL which can easily be decompiled - that would make your "password" easily retrievable. You could **obfuscate** your exe, but this isn't a 100% safe solution and SOMETIMES leads to other problems.